# Set node label in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to set a label instead of a name for nodes Groovy? We want to define labels outside the script to easily access them from the Jenkins Dashboard.

Idea:
Instead of:

---

**Groovy Script**

```
node('Slave_1 || Slave_2'){ echo 'Hello world' }
```

---

We want something like this:

---

**Pipeline configuration**

```
Node Label Name:     slaveGroup
Node Label Value:    Slave_1 || Slave_2
```

**Groovy Script**

```
node(slaveGroup){echo 'Hello world'}
```

Or is it possible to use the labels you can set in slave configuration directly in the Groovy script?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just found out that the Pipline Syntax (Generator) gives this option:

> ### Valid Operators
>
> The following operators are supported, in the order of precedence.
>
> (expr)
>
> parenthesis
>
> !expr
>
> negation
>
> expr&&expr
>
> and
>
> expr||expr
>
> or
>
> a -> b
>
> "implies" operator. Equivalent to !a|b. For example, windows->x64
> could be thought of as "if run on a Windows slave, that slave must be
> 64bit." It still allows Jenkins to run this build on linux.
>
> a <-> b
>
> "if and only if" operator. Equivalent to a&&b || !a&&!b. For example,
> windows<->sfbay could be thought of as "if run on a Windows slave,
> that slave must be in the SF bay area, but if not on Windows, it must
> not be in the bay area."
>
> All operators are left-associative (i.e., a->b->c <-> (a->b)->c ) An
> expression can contain whitespace for better readability, and it'll be
> ignored.
>
> Label names or slave names can be quoted if they contain unsafe
> characters. For example, "jenkins-solaris (Solaris)" || "Windows 2008"

More in the [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#valid-operators).

Comment: that is one valuable piece of information! especially the -> <->. this opens new possibilities!